# Hide window instead closing in Electron

Tags: macos, electron

My helper window is implemented like that:

```
    updWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 200,
        resizable: false,
        show: false,
        center: true,
        maximizable: false,
        minimizable: false,
        title: 'Apdate Available'
    });
    updWindow.on('close', function () {

    });
    updWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'updateAvailable.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
    updWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
```

When I click "x" button at window header the window will be closed and destroyed. So I will not be able to open it again using `updWindow` variable. Is there a way to keep window object for new opennings without reinitializations? I still want to use "x" button for this purpose.

My app is targeted to Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `preventDefault` on the event Electron will hand your handler over, i.e. like this:

```
updWindow.on("close", (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();    // This will cancel the close
    updWindow.hide();
});
```

This is mentioned in the [Electron documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs), namely [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-close).

Using this solution, you will later be able to un-hide the window by calling `updWindow.show();`.

Comment: Well, now I can reopen window using `updWindow.show();`. However the second and next times window opens in fullscreen. Seems like it just ignores my initial settings. How to fix?

Comment: It shouldn't, but you can restore (un-fullscreen) your window by calling `updWindow.unmaximize();`...